# What am I doing wrong with malloc and realloc of array of struct?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to build in C an array of structures without defining the length of the maximum size of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct text {
   char *final;
} text;

int main() {
    int n, sizearray = 10, i;
    char *str;
    text *testo;
    testo = (text *)malloc(sizeof(text) * sizearray);

    fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
    i = 0;
    while (str[0] != 'q') {
        if (i == sizearray - 1) {
            testo = (text *)realloc(testo, sizearray * 2 * sizeof(text));
        }
        n = strlen(str);
        n = n + 1;
        testo[i].finale = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        strcpy(testo[i].finale, str);
        i++;
        fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizearray; i++)
        printf("%s \n", testo[i].finale);

    return 0;
}
```

this gives me

> `process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEV).`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you didn't alloc memory for str, try, `char str [1024];`

Comment: Where does `str` point to? Also learn to use a debugger. The debugger would have told you _where_ the crash happened, which gives your valuable hints, for instance the crash most likely happens in `fgets` here, so the problem is not related to anything after `fgets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- **[major]** `str` is an uninitialized pointer. You should make it an array of `char` defined with `char str[1024]`.
- **[major]** you do not adjust `sizearray` when you double the size of the array, hence you will never reallocate the array after the initial attempt at `i = 9`.
- **[major]** the final loop goes to `sizearray` but there are potentially many uninitialized entries at the end of the array. You should stop at the last entry stored into the array.
- you should also check the return value of `fgets()` to avoid an infinite loop upon premature end of file.
- you should test for potential memory allocation failures to avoid undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct text {
   char *finale;
} text;

int main() {
    char str[1024];
    text *testo = NULL;
    size_t sizearray = 0;
    size_t i, n = 0;

    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) && *str != 'q') {
        if (n == sizearray) {
            /* increase the size of the array by the golden ratio */
            sizearray += sizearray / 2 + sizearray / 8 + 10;
            testo = realloc(testo, sizearray * sizeof(text));
            if (testo == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        testo[n].finale = strdup(str);
        if (testo[n].finale == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        n++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s", testo[i].finale);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(testo[i].finale);
    }
    free(testo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much, and what if i want to free just the space that i have not used?

Comment: You can add `text *tp = realloc(testo, n * sizeof(text)); if (tp != NULL) testo = tp;` after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is uninitialized. Either allocate memory with `malloc` or define it as an array with `char str[1024]`.